# Remember the question sort in the Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

I found an IMHO annoying behavior of the App: it does not save which question sort I'm using.

I normally use the "*Newest*" sort, but "*Active*" is always selected. As the default sort, I think it is okay, but it also changes back to the default when I look at a question and press the *Back* button.

It would be really useful if the app can remember the sort I'm using.